# Display SQL query result on front-end Wordpress site

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress, var-dump

I am trying to get the total data (SUM) within a column in a `Wordpress` database. I am using the following SQL (and PHP) code to run the request; however, I do not know how to display the result on the front end of my site.

```
global $wpdb;

$avg_items_purchased = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT SUM(items_purchased) FROM cogs');

print_r($avg_items_purchased);
```

or

```
var_dump($avg_items_purchased);
```

I have tried using `print_r($avg_items_purchased)`; and `var_dump($avg_items_purchased)`; but it outputs more information than I would like. Within the output, it prints the data that I am looking for, but I would like only the SUM of `items_purchased` to be displayed.

Is there a way I can simply output the variable, without the other data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a job for [$wpdb->get_var()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/get_var/). You'll get a cleaner output from something like this:

```php
global $wpdb;
$avg_items_purchased = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT SUM(items_purchased) FROM cogs');
?><p>Sum of items purchased: <?=$avg_items_purchased?></p><php?
```

It will be an HTML paragraph saying

> Sum of items purchased: 4.20